# Laravel blade problems with foreach array|object, null given

Tags: laravel, eloquent

First of all, forgive me for my English, it's not my native language and I don't know how to speak/write/express myself very well.

I have a problem with my view. I get the following error:

```
foreach() argument must be of type array|object, null given (View: /resources/views/admin/stages/index.blade.php)I get the following
```

in the query result, I see the stage array

[image: Query result]

Blade code:

```
@foreach($events as $event)
    <div class="box box-default">
        <div class="box-header with-border">
            <i class="fa fa-road"></i>
            <h3 class="box-title">{{ $event->name }}</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="box-body">
        @foreach($event->stages as $stage)
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
                    <!-- small box -->
                    <div class="small-box bg-light-blue-gradient">
                        <div class="inner">
                            <h3>SS{{ $stage->stage_num }}</h3>

                            <p>{{ $stage->name }}<br>{{ $stage->date }}</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="icon">
                            <i class="fa fa-map-signs"></i>
                        </div>
                        <a href="/admin/management/events/{{ $event->id }}/stages/{{ $stage->id }}/{{ $page }}" class="small-box-footer">{{ __(ucfirst($stage->state)) }} <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- ./col -->
        @endforeach
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.box -->
@endforeach
```

I update from Laravel 5.8 to 8.45.1

Thank you for all

Comment: `dump($event, $event->stages)` from inside the loop would be more helpful than `dump($events)`. Are you sure that every single `Event` instance has `stages`?

Comment: I just found the problem. In the model, the stages field was defined as fillable, when it shouldn't be, and that's why it was null. The strange thing is that with Laravel 5 it worked fine.